# Working on token authentication system and have a couple of questions about jsonwebtoken

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I have a decoupled Vue.js front-end + Node.js back-end and right now I'm trying to implement a token authentication system but I have a few questions.

```
jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256' }, function(err, token) {
  console.log(token);
});
```

First of all, in order to generate a token, the function requires a private/secret key. I'm a bit confused as to how this key is supposed to look like and whether it has to be the same for all tokens, or it should be unique. Also where should I store this key?

My second question is what is the payload supposed to consist of. In the example, { foo: 'bar' } is used as payload. In my application, after a user registers, I save his info in the database and get an object that looks like this:

```
    let user = {
        username: 'Test1',
        password: '$2a$12$lLnLRVHiI7yI4br.ys2aj.5EVcIjRD7BkV',
        email: 'test1@gmail.com'
    }
```

Do I just pass the user object as payload to jwt.sign() or should I just pass a single property?

Comment: "I'm trying to implement a token authentication system*" - why? What do you need the authentication for? What credentials will be used to login? Do you need session state?

Comment: @Bergi Is there something wrong with token authentication? I need authentication because some of the features I have in mind require the application to have registered users and authentication so I can protect some routes. Email and password will be used to login.

Comment: See http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/ and https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens for why you probably don't need (or want) tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, Your private token should be of sufficient length to make it harder to bruteforce.

2, It should be same for all tokens.

3, It should be stored safely on the server side. This question is impossible to answer without knowing your setup. But don't check it into git, don't put it in the client (for everyone to see).

4, Don't put secrets/passwords in the payload. These are not encrypted. You can take any token and decode them at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) without knowing the secret.

There is one important aspect that you are missing with the JWT. In the payload you can **verify** that the payload is created with your secret. However, the payload itself is **not encrypted**.

So you can put whatever you want to have verification on in the payload. A good usecase is a userId. If the verify on the token checks out you know that it was created with the secret. But it the secret is in the client every client can create a valid token. So make sure to actually keep it secret and on the server side. Don't ever put passwords or other secrets in the token. They will be 100% visible for everyone to see.